# Undefined method ` _path' on Show action of nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a rails rookie.

I did some routing changes on my first rails app, in this app you can create Congresses and each of those `has_many` categories, each category `belongs_to` (only one) Congress, so, my routes looks like this:

```
  resources :congresses do
    resources :categories do
      resources :presentations
    end
   resources :news
  end
```

I changed some things on views for Category, so, `link_to` now is in the form `congress_category_path`, those links works like a charm. After that, I add `[@congress, @category]` on the `form_for` category, so, the app lets you create a category. Here is where my problem starts...

at this part of view:

```
  <tbody>
<% Congress.find(params[:congress_id]).categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= category.name %></td>
    <td><%= category.description %></td>
    <td><%= category.presentations %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_congress_category_path(category) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

each category is an instance, `<%= link_to 'Show', category %>` extracts `category_path` and not `congress_category_path`... where can I change that specific route ?

this is giving me an

> undefined method `category_path` for `#<#<Class:0x9961e00>:0x929a360>`

I even tried something like

```
congress_category_path ([@congress, category])
```

but this didnt work either

I really appreciate your help, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've got the syntax wrong.

From here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects, your options for constructing a path out of nested resources are either:

```
congress_category_path(@congress, category)
```

or
(note the _path method does not accept an array parameter)

```
url_for([@congress, category])
```

(whereas the url_for method does).

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

several remarks

#### 1. limit resource depth

```
  resources :congresses do
    resources :categories do
      resources :presentations
    end
  end
```

The guidelines do not recommend having too nested routes. Instead you might want to take a look at [shallow routes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting)

#### 2 How path helpers are constructed

Next you need to understand that

```
resources :congresses do
  resources :categories
end
```

Generates CRUD routes of the following format (example for a `#show`)

```
GET /congresses/:congress_id/categories/:id => congresses/categories_controller#show
```

You can see that this "route" has two parameters `congress_id` and `id` so the path helpers that Rails generates can take two positional arguments `congress_id` and `id` and the path helpers are expected to be written as such

```
congress_category_path(@congress, category)
```

*Note : it is somewhat the equivalent of*

```
congress_category_path(congress_id: @congress.id.to_s, id: category.id.to_s)
```

#### 3 Using shallow routes you can use the simple route

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :congresses do
  resources :categories, shallow: true
end

# views/your_view.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Show', category %>
```